# Android Intercepting Events From Other Apps

Tags: android, intercept, listen

Does anyone knows how to intercept events from other 3rd party Apps, say, games, Maps, etc.
This includes events like motionevents, screen prompts, etc.

We have limited success with capturing touch events via the AccessibilityService, click, longclick, etc. But hitting a blank dealing with motionevents such as gestures or how the users are interacting with the screen.

(we have approval from users to capture such information in a control study)

We believe that if we root the phone (mess with the kernel) we can get such data but this inadvertently void the warranty on the user phone, so is there any other way to obtain such information on the API level?

Many thanks!

Comment: Rooting the phone will not help, in all likelihood. Modifying the firmware would.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are talking about your application gathering information about other applications life time interaction with the user then definitely no.

If this would be possible you could easily write a key logger and steal someones private data.