# Security Concerns for Keyboard input

Tags: android, root

I am aiming to find out different security concerns that can occur on Android devices .One of them is the Keyboard Interception

Following are my findings

a) If i am not using a third party IME (keyboard), i am sure that no application can intercept the keys that i have entered.

b)If i am using a third party IME app, this app can get whatever i have typed and may forward it to some other app/ upload it to the net etc.

Both above points are valid for a Non Rooted as well as a Rooted phone.

If i am using the standard keyboard (Android or that provided by firmware), it is impossible to intercept key events unless the firmware is modified
Links i refereed are [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974805/global-keyboard-input-listener-on-android) and [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666432/android-intercepting-events-from-other-apps)

What will happen if i plug in an external keyboard like we do on a Galaxy tab 2. When we type using this keyboard on the EditText on Activity at top, is it guaranteed that no one else can intercept the key presses(Rooted/Non rooted phones and without Firmware change)? I hope that the IME security rules given in Android Documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) under Security Section apply for external keyboards too.

I recently found the [DoMobile ShareKeyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.sharekeyboard) app on Market, it enables input through Computer keyboard using Wifi/GPRS on an Android device. Here obviously user is using a 3rd party IME so its completely insecure in cases where security is a major concern.

Please correct me if i am wrong in the points i mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we type using this keyboard on the EditText on Activity at top, is it guaranteed that no one else can intercept the key presses(Rooted/Non rooted phones and without Firmware change)?

Yes, if the OS is the one handling the keyboard.

Comment: What are the scenarios where OS will not handle the keyboard event ? This will not happen in case device is not rooted ,Am i right sir ?

Comment: @AlokKulkarni: "What are the scenarios where OS will not handle the keyboard event ?" -- non-standard keyboards might use an IME as a bridge between the hardware and Android, much like the "DoMobile ShareKeyboard" app you cited in your question.

Comment: Ok thanks.But as we cannot force an IME it's users choice for security. Maybe implementing a layout in the code for keyboard and using a Textview instead of Edittext to get user input might work

Answer (score 1):

a)You can't be sure. The original keyboard came with your device was made by your device manufacturer but might be modded until it got in your hands(by operators, resellers, rom modders, or just your boss)- its incredibly easy.
From my personal experience, firmware developers usually dont remember to clean debug information from their IME app, and all your keys(and even touch input) is printed in the logger.

b)Actually this might just be a more secure solution. you get it from Google Market, so you know nobody touched it in the way. These apps are also made by people who's expertise is building IME and therefore they'll know better how to improve its security and performance.

If your device is rooted you have no chance protecting your privacy at all, apps which will use root permissions will be able to read your keys from the lowest level possible - like /dev/input/eventX kernel input device not event talk about reading the Android key dispatcher which is also easy.

External keyboard is not different from virtual keyboard, its keys can be intercepted via the active IME app.

If your security is important to you, use official firmware, dont root your device, and use a good proven IME app from the Market which have security considered.

Comment: I am thinking of implementing my own keyboard like the one given here https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example . At least in case of unrooted device i will be sure that input given by the user will be from my app itself without user being able to use any IME